# Populate HTML select using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, listbox

I'm trying, without success, to fill an html select by using javascirpt (jquery).

I know how to fill a select with jquery (by using the method 'append').

What I can't do is that I have to read the value for the select, from a string that is in the following format: "AA,B,CCC,DD,E"; So the various values are separeted by a comma.

The result have to be the following:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="AA">AA</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
    <option value="DD">DD</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

Can someone help me ??

Thanks :)

---

How can I insert as 'value' for the select the values obtained from another string in the same format (str2= "1,2,3,4,5") ?

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="1">AA</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">CCC</option>
    <option value="4">DD</option>
    <option value="5">E</option>
</select>
```

Sorry for this questions, but I'm really new in js and jquery.

Thanks ;)

Comment: Show the JS you've got so far.

Comment: So, is the issue you're having splitting up the comma delimited string?  What have you tried so far and where is it not working?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it this way:

```
var str = "AA,B,CCC,DD,E";
var str2 = "1,2,8,4,5";
str = str.split(',');
str2 = str2.split(',');

$.each(str, function (idx, val) {
     $('#select1').append("<option value='" + str2[idx] + "'> " + val + " </option>");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple use of `.split()` will help.

```
var str = "AA,B,CCC,DD,E";
str = str.split(',');
$.each(str, function (idx, val) {
    console.log(val);
    $('#select').append("<option value='" + val + "'> " + val + " </option>");
});
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8BDm/).